# Android: cancelling pending events

Tags: android, events

I would like to be able to cancel all pending events in my App. How do I do it?

If many events stack up (due to the user "mashing" different areas of the screen repeatedly) I would like to cancel all events except the last one.

This is not the same as stopping the propagation of events further down the view stack (which is done by returning "true" from the event handler (for an example of this see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html#onLongClick%28android.view.View%29)).

Comment: If your event handling is so slow the events are stacking up, perhaps you should move that handling into a background thread instead.  Possibly even display a blocking "Loading ..." dialog, which should prevent events being triggered while the work is being done.  And if it's really slow, passing it off to a dedicated background service would probably be best.  If that doesn't make sense, perhaps I'm not understanding the question:  could you clarify what your app is doing while processing these events, and what type of events you need to cancel?

Comment: Sure Joe, I need to cancel touch events to the screen. My case is as follows: buttons are displayed to the user, in response to the users choice the buttons disappear and are replaced by other buttons. This happens in very rapid succession, with some animations taking place in between, I need to be able to block input during the in between time while the animation is running because I try to load the buttons as fast as possible so they may load before the animation finishes. After so more research I believe the answer lies in correctly implementing the onTouchEvent in the parent view.

Comment: Sure, you could use a `View.OnTouchListener`, depending on how you want your app to behave.  E.g., you might set a flag that indicates the user just pressed a button, and then schedule a `Runnable` that will toggle the flag after some delay;  then in the `OnTouchListener` (or really even the `OnClickListener` at that point), if the "quiet time" flag is set, simply discard the event.  If you do that in the `OnTouchListener` you may need to be careful though:  if you ignore the DOWN event, you won't receive the UP event either (could be what you want)